# Global variables and parallel processing

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I'm trying to process a large partitioned dataframe `partitions` using `pblapply` and `parallel`. However, global variables don't seem to be accessible to each thread.

`a` is another large dataframe. How can I make `a` accessible to the function?

See the dummy script below:

```
library(pbapply)
library(parallel)

partitions <- list(c(1:5),
                   c(6:10),
                   c(11:15))
a <- 1

myfn <- function(x, add = a) {
  out = x + a
  return(out)
}

pblapply(nums, myfn,
         cl = makeCluster(detectCores() - 1))
```

This throws the error:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  3 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'a' not found
```

Comment: With `parallel` alone, you need to export the data from the main R to each of the cluster nodes. If you read [`?parallel::clusterExport`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/parallel/versions/3.5.3/topics/clusterApply), you'll see examples that include `clusterExport(cl, "xx")` to transfer a variable named `xx` from the main console to all nodes in cluster `cl`. Similarly, you need to load libraries in each of them, such as `clusterEvalQ(cl, { library("sp"); library("rgeos"); })`.

Comment: If you use the [`future`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/index.html) package, it is much better about identifying (1) global variables that need to be transferred, and (2) global libraries that need to be available. In that case, it might not be necessary to do this extra step.

Comment: I was hoping to use the functions from [`pbapply`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pbapply/) so I could get the progress bar. Can you explain a little more about loading libraries and exporting data to each node?

Answer (score 2):

You should explicitly pass the `add` argument:

```
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
pblapply(
  partitions, 
  function(x, add) x + add, 
  cl = cl, 
  add = a
)
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass `x` and `add` to `myfn`?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. 
`x` is passed as each element of `partitions` and `add = a` is passed through the function thanks to the `...` of `lapply()`.